# Luatex paper size

Tags: luatex, plain-tex

I am looking into plain luatex (no latex). The following definitions change the size of the paper, but don't change the physical paper size. What am I missing

```
\newdimen\pagewidth
\newdimen\pageheight
\pagewidth=3.5in % the width of each page
\pageheight=3.7in % the height of each page
\def\setpage{\hsize\pagewidth\vsize\pageheight}
\setpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \eject




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\eject
\end
```

Comment: You want to reduce the `\vsize` by `\maxdepth`, so descenders in the last line will appear. Also the `\baselineskip` should be adjusted in order to fit an exact number of lines: `\vsize=\dimexpr\pageheight-\maxdepth\relax` and `\baselineskip=\dimexpr(\vsize-\topskip)/21\relax` will fit 22 lines on a baselineskip of 12.06661pt.

Comment: @egreg yes setting sensible margins was second level comment, but I decided to just stick to page size..

Answer (score 5):

you need to remove

```
\newdimen\pagewidth
\newdimen\pageheight
```

as they mask the primitives which if set will affect the size of the media box in the pdf. Also take account of the default 1in origin (currently you have `\hsize` equal to `\pagewidth` but offset by 1in.)

```
\pagewidth=3.5in % the width of each page
\pageheight=3.7in % the height of each page
\hoffset=-1in
\voffset=-1in
\def\setpage{\hsize\pagewidth\vsize\pageheight}
\setpage


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \eject
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\pdfvariable horigin=0pt` and `\pdfvariable vorigin=0pt`

Comment: @egreg yes but unless you have existing page layout macros using `\hoffset`  setting `\hoffset=-10in` or `horigin=0pt` comes to the same thing, I think.

Comment: No. One can then use `\hoffset` and `\voffset` for independent corrections if the printer driver has personal ideas.

Comment: @egreg shrug, if you are using plain and no other macros are in use, you could use `horigin` for independent corrections if your main code is using `\hoffset` or vice versa, the resulting pdf is the same whichever you set isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: remove your top two lines that declare `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight`, because those are actually the LuaTeX dimensions that you want to control.

---

In more detail:

- `\hsize` and `\vsize` are (roughly speaking) the dimensions within which TeX tries to typeset the content. In plain (Knuth) TeX, which produces only DVI, there is no further notion of physical paper size. But by default when printed the contents will appear at an offset of (1 inch + `\hoffset`) from the left edge of the paper, and (1 inch + `\voffset`) from the top edge.
- In pdfTeX (and XeTeX), `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` are the primitives that control the dimensions of the actual page in PDF. In LuaTeX, they [are](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/luatex/base/luatex.pdf#page=33) called simply `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight`.

When you use `\newdimen\pagewidth` you're clobbering the primitive so that it's no longer usable. So simply remove the top two lines in your question. Also, to account for the 1-inch margins, you should either make `\hoffset` and `\voffset` negative, or make the paper size bigger.

[image: output]

```
\pagewidth=5.5in % the width of each page
\pageheight=5.7in % the height of each page
\hsize=\dimexpr (\pagewidth - 2in) \relax
\vsize=\dimexpr (\pageheight - 2in) \relax

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \eject




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\eject
\end
```

(Also: using `\eject` without `\vfill` causes underfull vbox warnings.)

Comment: Oops, didn't notice answer was already posted while I was typing this.